# How to skip the root when walking the directory tree using for / R?

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a text file suicune in each directory of the tree except the root, but I also get a suicune txt file in the root.
I only want it in subfolders.

I have tried using different combinations in the set to skip the root. 
I have tried googling for a solution to skip the root. 
I have searched in the /?

```
REM creates text file suicune 
REM in each directory of the tree
set path="%C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Files%"
cd %path%

for /R %%a in (.) do (
    cd %%a
    echo hi > suicune.txt
)

pause
```

I expected a suicune.txt file to created only in subfolders of the directory but it's also created in the root directory.

Comment: `path` is a builtin environment variable and you are breaking your environment. Instead use `mypath` Also we do not use `%` in the variable values. Then simply exclude the root dir `do if not "%%~a"=="%mypath%."`

Comment: Replace `set path="%C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Files%"` by `set "MyPath="%UserProfile%\Desktop\Files""` for the reasons explained briefly by Gerhard Barnard and extended by answer on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

Comment: There's no need to change directory, or create variables, a single for loop should do what you wanted: `@For /D /R "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Files" %%A In (*)Do @CD.>"%%~A\suicune.txt"`.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard do if not check doesn't have any effect here

Comment: @Compo Thanks, this helped me! needed to use /D infront of /R and use (*) instead of (.)

Comment: `echo hi > suicune.txt` also outputs the _space_ before `>` to the file, better use `> "suicune.txt" echo hi` instead...

Comment: Yes, it will not have any effect if you do not use it correctly.